# How to check the serial number of element that have specific class using jquery?

Tags: jquery, class, serial-number

```
<ul>
    <li class="res"></li>
    <li class="res"></li>
    <li class="res selected"></li>
    <li class="res"></li>
</ul>
```

Using **$('ul li.selected').length** I can check total number of "selected elements" **BUT** I'd like to check the serial number of the "selected element" (in that case **3**)
Can you help me do that.
Thanks

Comment: It sounds like what you need is a barcode scanner

Comment: probably you mean index of the selected item instead of the serial number?

Comment: Yes I need the index but I didn't knew that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly do you mean by serial number?

The content?

```
 alert (  $('ul li.selected').text() );
```

The index?

```
 var listItem = $('ul li.selected');
 alert('Index: ' + $('ul li').index(listItem));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) method like this:

```
alert('Index: ' + $('li').index('.selected'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$("ul li.selected").index() + 1
```

Since [**`.index()`**](http://api.jquery.com/index/) is 0 based you need to add 1 to get your desired result.